# Does Haskell have something like gensym in Racket?

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, uniqueidentifier

1. It seems that Haskell does not the type of `symbol` as that in Racket?
2. Is there something that can generate symbols like `gensym` in Racket?
   e.g. in Racket, `(gensym 'label)` can give `'label2391`

Comment: are you looking in Template Haskell? I understand that's the Haskell equivalent to hygenic macros. Sorry if you are, I can't tell b/c I don't know it yet.

Comment: Since you know Haskell does not natively have symbols, what exactly do you expect the type of `gensym` to be? A `String`? I could imagine someone creating a `SymbolTableMonad` with a function similar to `gensym` and guarantees of uniqueness within the monad.

Comment: Yeah, it is kind of contradictory......I will see whether I definitely need something like that, then I will try to dig into Monad in Haskell as you suggested.

Comment: Look at the module `Data.Unique`, and don't hesitate to ask for help! You can't really generate unique identifiers with it, just unique numbers; but on the other hand, you don't really need to generate unique identifiers most of the time. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I think the unique identifiers may suffice... I am trying to simulate the concept of time, which increases monotonically, as well as address, which will be created on every new entry.

Comment: An edit describing what you actually want to do would be quite useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard unique supply is [`Data.Unique`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Data-Unique.html). For meta-programming purposes, Template Haskell also provides [unique names](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/2.5.0.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html).